# Изменение массива в методе Java

Tags: java, массивы, методы

Всем привет
Массив является ссылочным типом данных, тоесть если я сначала обьявил и проинициализировал его, затем изменил его в методе, вызвал этот метод и вывожу этот же массив на экран, мне должно показать измененный массив (так как в методе я работал с ссылкой, а не величиной)
Почему же, после вызова метода с этим массивом, мне выводит массив без изменений ?[image: ArrayChangeAfterUsingInMethod]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что Вы не *изменили* массив, который передали, а *создали* новый.

```
d = MethodWith...(d);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, действительно совершил ошибку.
Подскажите пожалуйста, почему for (foreach в Java) не изменяют элементы массива ?
Потому что  изменения инкрементной переменной в цикле foreach меняет только ее саму, а не элементы массива ?
    static int[] MethodWithLinkedTypesOfVariables2(int [] a)
    {
        for (int i: a)
        {
            i = i+12;
            System.out.print(i + " "); Выводит 12, 12, 12 (0+12)
        }
        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
            System.out.print(a[i] + " !"); Выводит 0, 0, 0
}

Comment: @Mr.StupidQuestions Пожалуйста. Успехов.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, почему for (foreach в Java) не изменяют элементы массива ?
Потому что  изменения инкрементной переменной в цикле foreach меняет только ее саму, а не элементы массива ?
    `static int[] MethodWithLinkedTypesOfVariables2(int [] a)
    {
        for (int i: a)
        {
            i = i+12;
            System.out.print(i + " "); Выводит 12, 12, 12 (0+12)
        }
        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
            System.out.print(a[i] + " !"); Выводит 0, 0, 0
}`

Comment: @Mr.StupidQuestions Потому что `i` - это отдельная переменная, куда скопировано целое значение из элемента массива.